# How to put together two queries of same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have trouble with joining two query into one.

query 1:

```
SELECT *
FROM (`text`)
WHERE `text` LIKE '%TERM1%' ORDER BY `text`.`start` DESC
```

query 2:

```
SELECT *,
  MATCH (col1,  col2,  col3) AGAINST ('%TERM2%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM `text`
WHERE MATCH (col1, col2, col3) AGAINST ('%TERM2%' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
      AND status=2
ORDER BY `text`.`start` DESC
```

any suggestion would be accepted.

Table 'text' look like

```
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
|  col1 |  col2  | col3  | text |  id  |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
| name1 | place1 | date1 | val1 |   1  |
| name2 | place2 | date2 | val2 |   2  |
| name3 | place2 | date5 | val1 |   3  |
| name4 | place4 | date4 | val5 |   4  |
| name5 | place5 | date5 | val5 |   5  |
:
:
| namex | placex | datex | valx |   x  |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
```

I have forgot to write, first query also must be ordered by start DESC...

I expect result like: term1 = val1, and term2 = val5

```
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
|  col1 |  col2  | col3  | text |  id  |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
```

qery1 result:

```
| name3 | place2 | date5 | val1 |   3  |
| name1 | place1 | date1 | val1 |   1  |
```

query2 result

```
| name5 | place5 | date5 | val5 |   5  |
| name4 | place4 | date4 | val5 |   4  |
:
:
| namex | placex | datex | valx |   1  |
+-------+--------+-------+------+------+
```

Thanks.

@PinnyM - Yes table are named `text` and inside table stand column `text`, unfortu, I have adopt project with complete database, and it was absurdly, but also it is absurdly go to change complete code because it is necessary or not change of table name.

Comment: By 'join them' what do you want the result to look like?  And please don't tell me you really have a table named '`text`'...

Comment: Just a note, if you're trying to combine the queries with a UNION operator, each query much return the same number of columns. If that's not what you're trying to do, how do you want to join the queries? On what criteria?

Comment: And you should not use select*  for any code that will go to production. This is a SQL antipattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way:

```
SELECT t.*, -1 as relevance
FROM `text` t
WHERE `text` LIKE '%TERM1%'
union all
SELECT t.*, MATCH (col1,  col2,  col3) AGAINST ('%TERM2%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance
FROM `text` t
WHERE MATCH (col1, col2, col3) AGAINST ('%TERM2%' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND status=2
ORDER BY `text`.`start` DESC
```